# C++ Printing exactly what the user entered

Tags: c++

I am trying to print an array that has values like 3.0, 1, 2, 4.00, 40.000
so for example i want to save exactly what the user enters and prints it, like if for the first field they enter 1, it will print 1, if they enter 2.0 it will print 2.0 and the same goes for the other values.

Comment: Is it really your end goal? Just echoing user input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then store the value in a string. While a floating point "2.0" could be displayed as "2.0" or "2", the string "2.0" will always be exactly those characters.

Comment: Like? Can you show me an example? I've tried this:
https://hastebin.com/icanijumok.cpp
but it didn't work, it crashes when i entered a value with .

Comment: @Zakra: The problem with your question is that it's just too broad. You haven't indicated where you are getting stuck. Should I assume that you don't know anything about working with strings or what? How are you inputing the data? I don't want to just write the code for you. Update your question and tell us where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Nevermind, I've fixed my problem, the code I've just showed you is the correct one to do something like that. I was just doing something wrong while entering the values. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @Zakra: Can I make a suggestion? Next time you ask a question, include the code. Then stick around because you'll get the most replies right away. Failing to include details or not being there to answer questions will make it much harder to get a good answer.

Comment: Alright sure, I was in a hurry and i completely forgot to post my code. Thanks for the help!